# CN1 CameraKit gives null PeerComponent

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying the default code in the Readme of the CameraKit CN1Lib on a new bare bones project:
https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne

It works in the simulator with the webcam, but on a real Android device the line `hi.add(ck.getView());` throws an exception because of a null object reference.

I suspect that the problem is that the camera permissions are not asked.

However, in the `codenameone_settings.properties`, there is the line:

```
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.CAMERA" required\="true"/><uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" required\="true"/>
```

so I don't know how to solve this issue.

This don't seem related to the new Android API, because the issue exists also with:

```
codename1.arg.android.targetSDKVersion=28
codename1.arg.android.buildToolsVersion=28
```

Comment: What's the device and OS version?
Do you see anything in the device logs?

Comment: I understood the cause of the problem, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the use of `ck.start();` and `ck.stop();`, as in this example:
https://github.com/codenameone/CameraKitCodenameOne/blob/master/CameraKitDemo/src/com/codename1/camerakit/demo/CameraKitDemo.java

Without `ck.start();`, `ck.getView()` returns null.

So the example in the ReadMe is not usable as it is, because it doesn't invoke `ck.start();` neither `ck.stop();`